# VBA code for deleting and creating relationships adding same ID records in the child table, is it possible?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that I create every time with updated data from a main database.
so there is a MAIN database with all the data, from that I query and get a dataset which I save as a table lets call it (TABLE1),  in a small access database.
The MAIN database gets updated manually by me and some other colleagues and then I delete the old table on my access database and create a new one (TABLE1),  with the updated data.
The updated data represents new records, and some updated fields on existing records.

I have another table (TABLE2), on my access database with some extra data related to the records in (TABLE1).
Every time I do this I have to break up the relationship link I have within the tables ID fields via VBA. 
Then I have to add empty rows in TABLE2 to match TABLE1 and recreate the relationship.
Can it be done better with VBA code?

Example:

```
TABLE1
-------
name
-------
'cat'
'dog'
'mouse'

TABLE2
------
cost
------
23
13
25
```

Query based oon ID fields (autonumber)

```
-------|-----
name   |cost
-------|------
'cat'  |23
'dog'  |13
'mouse'|25
```

Comment: And they are related by what?? why you need to delete the table? why you have a related table if you are deleting the parent (thus loosing all the relation idea??)

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to delete TABLE1 so that you can then recreate it with a fresh set of data.  Instead, discard the existing rows ...

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1;
```

... then append your new rows to it ...

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (
    fld1,
    fld2,
    etc
    )
SELECT
    fld1,
    fld2,
    etc
FROM MAIN
WHERE <the condition which identifies the new records>;
```

However I'm unsure how that applies to the existing relationship.  If you're not enforcing relational integrity, that may be enough.

If you still need to delete the relationship, you can remove it from your database's Relations collection.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Relations.Delete "YourRelationName"
Set db = Nothing
```

Later, to recreate the relationship you can use the [Database.CreateRelation Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221012%28office.12%29.aspx).  That will likely be more involved than deleting the relationship.  See this detailed example: [VBA code for creating MS Access Relations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37179/VBA-code-for-creating-MS-Access-Relations)

Comment: would this create new ID autonumber fields in the child table(TABLE2). they are only related by the ID field. (Table1)ID1 = (Table2)ID1 and so on.